# how to rename a file using part of a name stored in a variable

Tags: bash

Hello everybody i'd like to know how to rename a file using part of a name stored in a variable. To be more clear i'll show you an example.
Let's say i have to loop through all the files called test_*.txt so test_1.txt, test_2.txt ... test_45.txt and so on.
At a point in the loop i need to rename a file test-name.txt in test-name1.txt, test-name2.txt according to the number in the test_1.txt file

```
 for test in test_*.txt
 do 
     'rename test-name.txt to test-name(number in test).txt'
 done
```

Comment: Once `test-name.txt` has been renamed to `test-name1.txt` which file will be renamed to `test-name2.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for tst in test_*.txt
do
    nr=${tst#test_}  # Delete 'test_' from beginning of file name in tst
    nr=${nr%.txt}    # Delete '.txt' from end of file name in tst
    mv test_name.txt test_name_${nr}.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pattern matching in bash:

```
[[ $file =~ test_(.*).txt ]];
mv test_name.txt test_name${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt
```